# Qt sort columns

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I have a Qt widget with a treeView, which gets updated from outside the component (every couple of miliseconds). I have added a header to the treeView and I now wish to sort the elements:

`treeView->header()->setClickable(true);
 treeView->header()->setSortIndicatorShown(true);`

I can click on the header and the idems do get sorted, but once new data comes and fills the tree, I wish it to automatically update. What would be the easiest way to do so?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QSortFilterProxyModel`  for this purpose.

```
 QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView;
 MyItemModel *sourceModel = new MyItemModel(this);
 QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);

 proxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);
 treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
```

When you get and set new data, use `void QSortFilterProxyModel::sort ( int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder )` method

For example:

```
proxyModel->sort(1);
```

It seems you use `QTimer`, so you can use `sort()` method in the slot which connected to `timeout` signal.